# Searching for Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm attempting to print factory bbb_a.

I have two models

- aaa has_many bbbs
- bbb belongs_to aaa

*aaas.rb*

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :aaa do
    after(:build) do |aaa|
      aaa.bbbs << build(:bbb_a)
      aaa.bbbs << build(:bbb_b)
    end
  end
end
```

*bbbs.rb*

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :bbb do
    factory :bbb_a do
    end
    factory :bbb_b do
    end
  end
end
```

*aaa_spec.rb*

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe Aaa do
  it "works" do
    aaa = FactoryGirl.create(:aaa)
    puts aaa.bbbs(:bbb_a) #This gives both bbb_a and bbb_b
    aaa.should_not be_nil
  end
end
```

*Console Output*

```
Bbb 1
Bbb 2
.

Finished in 0.11593 seconds
1 example, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 44359
```

*What I Expected*

```
Bbb 1
.

Finished in 0.11593 seconds
1 example, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 44359
```

Why is it that it puts both bbb_a and bbb_b? How can I get it to just print bbb_a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to replace

```
puts aaa.bbbs(:bbb_a)
```

With either

```
puts aaa.bbbs.first
```

Or

```
puts aaa.bbbs[0]
```

Because you have a has_many relationship between `Aaa` and `Bbb` models, rails creates dynamic instance methods for you as `Aaa#bbbs` and `Bbb#aaa`.
This method accept 0 or 1 arguments. If you pass an argument to this method as `true` then it fires the query on the database to retrieve the associated records. And If you pass an argument to this method as `false` then it just picks up the cached results of the query (provided query was fired once before for the caching to take place).

So, when you do

```
puts aaa.bbbs(:bbb_a)
```

The value passed is simply ignored as its neither `true` or `false`.

Comment: Say I have a 1000 of these bbbs and I don't know which [#] goes to which value. Is there any way to search for a value?

Comment: If you know the value of some unique attribute or the id then just specify it `aaa.bbbs.where(attr1: value)`